# How to train my dog not to bark at sounds coming from neighborhood?

Tags: training, vocalizations

My dog is about 8 months old, so technically still a puppy. He barks at sounds coming from neighborhood, such as other dogs barking around, sounds of kids, etc.

Is there a practical way to end up this issue?

He doesn’t bark anymore against certain sounds that he used to bark against until about 2 months ago. So is it likely that he bark less when he grew older.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to be "on his side", and teach him when it is OK to bark and when not. Whenever he barks "without a reason" just talk to him and "explain" that the neighborhood sounds are OK. He will not understand all the explanation, but:

- he will be happy that you "socialize with him";
- he will gradually learn when barking is not OK.

The downside is that if it happens during the night, it might not be very comfortable for you - but the barking is not comfortable either so...

---

Alternatively, there are (electronic) anti-barking devices - when the dog barks too loud, they emit some ultrasound, which is painful for the dog. And he will learn "by pain" that any loud barking is forbidden.

Comment: Is is ok to use the electronic devices? First, isn’t it too cruel? Second, does that way really work? I know there are collars the give electronic shock to the dog when he barks. But I don’t know if that way is morally right. And if it is, whether it works.

Comment: @Sasan: yes, collars exist also. I am personally against using pain as a training device. That is why I focused my answer on socializing training - dogs are intelligent beings, after all. If the devices do not bother the neighbors, they should be OK. Are they cruelty to the dog? Kind of yes, of course.

Comment: @Sasan you should ask a second question about electronic devices, or edit your question and include, if electric devices may be a solution. So you get more focused answers which will better help you

Comment: @Sasan look at my answer to this question, which addresses why electric collars are bad. https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/do-electronic-collars-work-for-barking

Comment: @Sasan oh wait, this is your question lol

Comment: @Xenon Yes. And I left a comment for you there.